# Python Pandas Data sampling/aggregation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a huge comma separated datetime, `unique_id` dataset which looks as below.

```
datetime, unique_id
2016-09-01 19:50:01, bca8ca1c91d283212faaade44c6185956265cc09 
2016-09-01 19:50:02, ddd20611d47597435412739db48b0cb04599e340 
2016-09-01 19:50:10, 5b8776d7dc0b83f9bd9ad70a403a5f605e37d4d4 
2016-09-01 19:50:14, 2b8a2d7179fe08f8c87d125ad5bc41b5eb79d06f 
2016-09-01 19:50:20, 902c4428e08f4324a70a5a4bbfabb657c4a9ffc3 
2016-09-01 19:50:23, bca8ca1c91d283212faaade44c6185956265cc09 
2016-09-01 19:51:10, a2e6521c66e7207398ffe3d4e5bab449f75e616d 
2016-09-01 19:51:11, a2e6521c66e7207398ffe3d4e5bab449f75e616d 
2016-09-01 19:51:20, f7cfa02eeb3feed2a0f616185312925e4190c66b 
2016-09-01 19:51:30, 0bb21868b55b832f1315438ccdb9c508cf37b8b4 
2016-09-01 19:51:40, cb3cfe7bc2fa40d20db23ddc209d2062e10c2ce3 
2016-09-01 19:51:50, 2b8a2d7179fe08f8c87d125ad5bc41b5eb79d06f 
2016-09-01 19:51:55, 099ba09cd602f9d9bb20f5ebc195686dc133b464 
2016-09-01 19:52:00, c300e6a54013ee56facab294e326aa523cd4c60a 
2016-09-01 19:53:01, bca8ca1c91d283212faaade44c6185956265cc09 
2016-09-01 19:53:04, 902c4428e08f4324a70a5a4bbfabb657c4a9ffc3 
2016-09-01 19:53:10, 5b8776d7dc0b83f9bd9ad70a403a5f605e37d4d4 
2016-09-01 19:53:11, 2b8a2d7179fe08f8c87d125ad5bc41b5eb79d06f 
2016-09-01 19:53:17, bca8ca1c91d283212faaade44c6185956265cc09 
2016-09-01 19:53:20, 0fe1560c790c78b960b66e7d7336dd76d2ea12cf 
2016-09-01 19:53:40, ddd20611d47597435412739db48b0cb04599e340
```

Using Python Pandas, I would like to get count of `unique ids` per `minute`.
For ex.

```
datetime, count(unique_id)
2016-09-01 19:50:00, 5 
2016-09-01 19:51:00, 6 
2016-09-01 19:52:00, 1 
2016-09-01 19:53:00, 6
```

I tried using `pandas.DataFrame.resample` but looks like that is not the way to approach this problem.

```
resampled_data = raw_df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(raw_df["datetime"])).resample("1T")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the datetime as index and use the `pandas.TimeGrouper` to create the group variable, which can group your data frame with specified frequency in time, and then count the number of unique ids:

```
import pandas as pd
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)).groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq = "min"))['unique_id'].nunique()

#           datetime
#2016-09-01 19:50:00    5
#2016-09-01 19:51:00    6
#2016-09-01 19:52:00    1
#2016-09-01 19:53:00    6
#Freq: T, Name: unique_id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need specify `Series` - `['unique_id']` and add  [`Resampler.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.nunique.html):

```
resampled_data = raw_df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(raw_df["datetime"]))
                       .resample("1T")['unique_id']
                       .nunique()
print (resampled_data)
2016-09-01 19:50:00    5
2016-09-01 19:51:00    6
2016-09-01 19:52:00    1
2016-09-01 19:53:00    6
Freq: T, Name: unique_id, dtype: int64
```